# Getting NaN for 0% in MS Column Chart?

Tags: asp.net, web, charts, bar-chart, mschart

I have a column chart shows data from database and shows it in % . it works fine but when it doesn't return any result .chart should show 0% but instead of 0% it is showing NaN. Want to show it as 0%
want to show 0% in series label

```
if (platForms != null)
                        foreach (var platForm in platForms)
                        {
                            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                            dr["Platform"] = platForm;
                            dr["Count"] = GetPlatformCount(temp, platForm);
                            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                        }

                    chartWorkItemsPlatform.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
                    chartWorkItemsPlatform.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "Platform";
                    chartWorkItemsPlatform.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "Count";
                    chartWorkItemsPlatform.Series["Series1"]["DrawingStyle"] = "Emboss";
                    chartWorkItemsPlatform.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
                    chartWorkItemsPlatform.Series["Series1"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
                    chartWorkItemsPlatform.Series["Series1"].IsVisibleInLegend = true;
                    chartWorkItemsPlatform.Series["Series1"].IsXValueIndexed = true;
                    chartWorkItemsPlatform.Series["Series1"].Label = "#PERCENT";
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to change the column chart, but if the data is coming from the database, adjust the query to return 0 when that column is null.